# How to hide a section in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My application has a photo album page that based on UICollection view. This album page may contain more than one album and each album actually is a section of UICollectionView that contains stacked photos. That photos are located in UICollectionCells.

When a user tapped on an album I want other albums to disappear and tapped album's stacked photos spread on whole screen.

1. How could I hide a section in a collection view?
2. Is there a 3rd party library to make this kind of photo album.

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the collection view with the new data (from the selected album) or move to another view controller with new collection view that shows all the pictures from the selected album